# How to click a view that is behind a scrollview

Tags: android

I have to an `EditText` behind a `ScrollView`

I cannot click the `EditText` anymore. The `ScrollView` is intercepting it I think. I tried the code below but it doesn't fix it.

Any suggestions?

```
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
```

Comment: What would be a use case for an edit text behind a scrollview?

Comment: why are you trying to click a view which is not even visible?

Comment: @arol_8021 no im not trying to click a view thats not visible. its visible behind the scrollview. the scrollview occupies the whole screen

Comment: Could we have more of the layout, please? Specifically, where the editText is in relation to the ScrollView

Comment: Please post the whole layout with EditText.

Comment: Just put the EditText inside the ScrollView.

Comment: how do you expect to scroll it if you can't touch it?

Answer (score 1):

Things to try:

- The parent view can influence the position of the views.  For example
  in a `FrameLayout` all of the views get stacked in the order they are
  placed in the layout file (so your issue could be fixed by
  rearranging the order of the `EditText` in relation to the
  `ScrollView`).
- You might try to call [editText.bringToFront()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#bringToFront()) to force the
  `EditText` in front of the `ScrollView`.
- If you disable the touch-based listeners (`OnClickListeners`, etc) on
  the `ScrollView` or the container it's in then the action should "pass
  through" the `ScrollView` and allow you to interact with the `EditText`
  behind it. I found this out the hard way when I was trying to make
  the opposite scenario work for me (I wanted the top level view to
  consume the actions and not fall through to the view behind it).

These solutions worked for me in the past in different scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I replaced `android:layout_height="match_parent"` to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` and views inside ScrollView become clickable. Hope this helps.

My code:

```
v<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="WRAP_CONTENT"
    android:id="@+id/svTabActions">
<View>...</View>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try placing the `editText` inside the `scrollView`.